Writing SQL Query With Same Client ID , same Tax_year, same Tax_effective_date But with Different Tax_id & Payroll_ID in ORACLE SQL
I have a table like below data:

Now One query need to be written where logic will be like: Same client Id(duplicate client_id), same Tax_year, same Tax_effective_date but with different tax_code and Payroll_id.Other column's data should be displayed as it is.
Expected Output:

I have tried to write the query using CTE table, but not able to get proper result. Could anyone please help me on this to write the query.

Please don’t use screenshots (as no one can copy your data if they want to try a solution) , add all data as editable text formatted as tables


Same client Id(duplicate client_id), same Tax_year, same Tax_effective_date but with different tax_code and Payroll_id.

You can use multiple columns filtering in Where clause using IN(... subquery ...)
--      S Q L : 
Select   t.*
From     tbl t
Where  (CLIENT_ID, TAX_YEAR, TAX_EFFECTIVE_DATE) 
        IN( Select   CLIENT_ID, TAX_YEAR, TAX_EFFECTIVE_DATE
            From     tbl 
            Group By CLIENT_ID, TAX_YEAR, TAX_EFFECTIVE_DATE 
            Having Count(*) > 1 And                   -- Same client Id(duplicate client_id), same Tax_year, same Tax_effective_date
                   Count(DISTINCT TAX_CODE) > 1 And   -- different tax_code
                   Count(DISTINCT PAYROLL_ID) > 1)    -- different payroll_id
Order By t.CLIENT_ID, t.TAX_CODE

/*      R e s u l t :
CLIENT_ID   TAX_CODE    TAX_YEAR    TAX_EFFECTIVE_DATE  PAYROLL_ID  GROSS_PAID  TAX_PAID
----------  ----------  ----------  ------------------  ----------  ----------  --------
123         BR          2018        12-NOV-17           780PR               56         0
123         MT          2018        12-NOV-17           673Y             43.94     12.23
789         789Y        2017        12-NOV-17           4567Z            43.94     12.23
789         GH          2017        12-NOV-17           4567R            43.94     12.23

See the fiddle here.

This gets invalid matches. fiddle only has one valid pair but it returns all 3 rows.

@MT0 In OP's data for each client_id there are tax_code and payroll_id Like as a pair) that doesn't mix up like in your fiddle : The sample data provided is quite clear like - one client_id (123) has tax_code - payroll_id either as 1100L - 11890/TT (twice the same combo) or BR - 780PR or MT - 673Y.  If the data could be mixed up like in your fiddle that would for sure be in the OP's original sample data and presented in the expected result.

Thank You Very Much @d r it really helped me a lot !!!

@Node98 You are welcome.

You can join the table to itself to find matching pairs and then UNPIVOT to separate the matched values into two rows:
SELECT client_id,
       tax_year,
       tax_effective_date,
       tax_code,
       payroll_id,
       gross_paid,
       tax_paid
FROM   (
  SELECT t1.client_id,
         t1.tax_year,
         t1.tax_effective_date,
         t1.tax_code AS tax_code1,
         t2.tax_code AS tax_code2,
         t1.payroll_id AS payroll_id1,
         t2.payroll_id AS payroll_id2,
         t1.gross_paid AS gross_paid1,
         t2.gross_paid AS gross_paid2,
         t1.tax_paid AS tax_paid1,
         t2.tax_paid AS tax_paid2
  FROM   table_name t1
         INNER JOIN table_name t2
         ON (   t1.client_id          = t2.client_id
            AND t1.tax_year           = t2.tax_year
            AND t1.tax_effective_date = t2.tax_effective_date
            AND t1.tax_code           < t2.tax_code
            AND t1.payroll_id         != t2.payroll_id )
)
UNPIVOT (
  (tax_code, payroll_id, gross_paid, tax_paid)
  FOR match IN (
    (tax_code1, payroll_id1, gross_paid1, tax_paid1) AS 1,
    (tax_code2, payroll_id2, gross_paid2, tax_paid2) AS 2
  )
)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  client_id,
  tax_year,
  tax_effective_date,
  tax_code,
  payroll_id,
  gross_paid,
  tax_paid
) AS
SELECT 1, 2020, DATE '2024-01-01', 'AAA', 111, 100, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2020, DATE '2024-01-01', 'AAA', 222, 100, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2020, DATE '2024-01-02', 'BBB', 333, 100, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2020, DATE '2024-01-02', 'CCC', 444, 200, 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2020, DATE '2024-01-01', 'AAA', 111, 100, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2020, DATE '2024-01-01', 'BBB', 111, 100, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2020, DATE '2024-01-01', 'AAA', 111, 100, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2020, DATE '2024-01-01', 'BBB', 222, 200, 30 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



CLIENT_ID
TAX_YEAR
TAX_EFFECTIVE_DATE
TAX_CODE
PAYROLL_ID
GROSS_PAID
TAX_PAID




1
2020
2024-01-02 00:00:00
BBB
333
100
20


1
2020
2024-01-02 00:00:00
CCC
444
200
40


3
2020
2024-01-01 00:00:00
AAA
111
100
20


3
2020
2024-01-01 00:00:00
BBB
222
200
30



fiddle
